# Javascript - Progress bar value not changing with selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown list. On selection of the list a value changes. But the value of the progress bar does not changes.

For example: On loading of page the value should be 415760 (100% full Progress bar)

On selection of 9, the value should be 300000 (72% of progress bar)

On selection of 11, the value should be 0 (0% of progress bar)

Here is the code: http://codepen.io/neonirav/pen/qlgCD

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the value of your progress bar! by default `value='0'` a number, not a string as you did.

```
 <progress max="415760" name="gm_ro_total" id="gm_ro_total" value='0'></progress>
```

Then change

```
var gm_ro_total = parseInt(gmro1.value);
gm_remainingoil.innerHTML = gm_ro_total;
```

with

```
var gm_ro_total = parseInt(gmro1.value),
    gm_ro_totalElement = document.getElementById('gm_ro_total');
  gm_ro_totalElement.value= parseInt(gm_ro_total);
gm_remainingoil.innerHTML = gm_ro_total;
```

Comment: This answer is correct. But, I am stucked again in further work. Here is the code: http://codepen.io/neonirav/pen/okdmC : where I stucked for the progress bar of the Total of the 2 or more things. From viewing the code you will be able to understand where is the error. Please help.

Comment: Consider accepting my answer please! your last line should be `gmroprt.value = gm_ro_total;` see this http://cdpn.io/okdmC

Comment: Is it possible to make 2 values for the same drop down working like the following excel sheet. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r-Lzgzo4yX_4sdHuFx42Pw5gLdMG8odlXypgryql3Nk/edit?usp=sharing

On this drop down code of the earlier one. Only value of time remaining to be displayed.
http://codepen.io/neonirav/pen/jnvmd

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand your last question! Please try to be clear

Answer (score 1):

I have forked your code pen with what I think you need:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/djhnk

You were setting `.value` on a div, not on the progress bar element.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly correct. But, I was am stucked again in further work. Here is the code: http://codepen.io/neonirav/pen/okdmC  :
where I stucked for the progress bar of the Total of the 2 or more things. From viewing the code you will be able to understand where is the error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should set value for Progres bar and not the div. Is this what you need? `Code` [Click here to view](http://jsfiddle.net/yKeqA/)

Comment: this is not an answer, you should post in `OP` question comment